# How to get Instance of a Mat-Table, If we have multiple tables in the component

Tags: angular, mat-table

Am struck with some issue. I have a component in Angular 6 where am generating multiple Mat-Tables with Data. Am using the ng-for loop in the div tag to loop through all the Mat-Table Data sources. Later am trying to add a new row to the table . Till here it is fine, But am not able to get the Instance of the table for which this Add Row function is clicked. In .ts fenter code hereile with the help of View-Child am always getting the instance of the 1st table only. I would like to get the instance of all the table, with which I will call the render rows function to refresh that selected MatTable in the view

Pasted  Sample code for the View and TS File. Note Add is not working now.

```
   <div *ngFor="let data of ViewContent">
<button (click)="addElement(event,data?.tableValues,displayedColumns)">Add element</button> <br />
<table   #testTable mat-table [dataSource]="data?.tableValues">

  <!-- Col1 Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Col1">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Col1 </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Col1}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Col2 Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Col2">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Col2 </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Col2}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Col3 Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Col3">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Col3 </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Col3}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>



<!-- Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->

</div>



import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {Component,OnInit,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import  DalContentdata from 'Content.json';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'cdk-table-basic-example.html',
})
export class CdkTableBasicExample implements OnInit  {
   ViewContent: Object;
   displayedColumns: string[] = ['Col1','Col2','Col3'];

  @ViewChild('testTable') table: MatTable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ViewContent =  [
    {
      "title":"abc",
      "tableValues": [
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
       "title":"abc",
      "displayColumns": "Col1,Col2,Col3",
      "tableValues": [
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
       "title":"abc",
      "displayColumns": "Col1,Col2,Col3",
      "tableValues": [
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Apple",
          "Col2": "Mango",
          "Col3": "Orange"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  }


  addElement(event, title, tableDataSource, displayColumns) {
        console.log('beforeAdd', tableDataSource);
    tableDataSource.push({
      Col1: 'Test',Col2:'Test',Col3:'Test'
    })
     console.log('afteradd', tableDataSource);
     this.table.renderRows();

    console.log('afteradd', tableDataSource);
  }


}


/**  Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

Comment: *Edit*: Can you remove unecessary codes and add the function you use to add new line.

Comment: Hi Wandrille I have removed the old code and kept the sameple code. Hope this helps.

Comment: use @Viewchildren() 
@ViewChildren() _tables: QueryList<any>

then you can either use this._tables.toArray();  to loop  through

Comment: @Roj, thanks for the input. this._tables.toArray() gives me to access all the tables. But how to call the renderRows for  the required table. For instance lets say this._tables.toArray() returns 4 tables. And I want to call the renderRows() on 2nd table, how to do that. It is giving me result as undefined if am doing so. I want to call the RenderRows() to refresh that table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Roj any help on this please.

Comment: @Roj can you help on my request pls.thanks for the input. this._tables.toArray() gives me to access all the tables. But how to call the renderRows for the required table. For instance lets say this._tables.toArray() returns 4 tables. And I want to call the renderRows() on 2nd table, how to do that. It is giving me result as undefined if am doing so. I want to call the RenderRows() to refresh that table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Massimiliano Sartoretto Any help on this one is also more useful.Thank you.

Comment: @k0hamed Can you please guide me in this issue as well

Comment: fixed this one on on lines inf Roj direction. We ned to create an instance 
  @ViewChildren('dalTable') table: QueryList<any>; Then after any add/Delete we can render rows by calling   this.table.toArray().forEach(data => data.renderRows()); This will refresh all the table rows

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by using ViewChildren rather than ViewChild.

I initially had:

```
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<string>;
```

and to call renderRows on it, I was calling

```
this.table.renderRows();
```

However, I then needed another table in the same component, so my code changed to:

```
@ViewChildren(MatTable) table !: QueryList<MatTable<string>>;
```

and

```
this.table.first.renderRows();
this.table.last.renderRows();
```

With first and last being properties of queryList.
https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#properties

Make sure you're importing MatTable

```
import { MatTable } from "@angular/material/table";
```

Comment: how should we use this when we have more than 2 tables?

Comment: @VigneshSubramanian Little late: You just use the .get(index) method of QueryList to get appropiate element.

Answer (score 2):

you should use ViewChild.

html:
let's assume that your tables running inside a for loop with and index variable named i:

```
  <table id="testTable{{i}}" [dataSource]="yourDataSource"><!--data source can be set from ts as well-->
```

ts:

```
@ViewChild('testTable1') matTable1: MatTable<any>;
  @ViewChild('testTable2') matTable2: MatTable<any>;
  @ViewChild('testTable3') matTable3: MatTable<any>;
```

or of course just can just use an array.

don't forget to import it, and you will prefer to use AfterViewInit lifecycle hook

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
//    this.matTable...
  }
```

Edit:

if you wish to refresh your data source

this.matTable.dataSource=[...this.data]

you can just pass new array (with a new reference) and it will trigger the data change and you data table will refresh

If you wish to create a unic ID for every table using for,

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt response. But this didn't resolve my issue. Here In the UI We will have 3 Mat-Tables with an Add button at the top of each table. Requirement is When we click "ADD" a new record will be added at the top of the corresponding table.Here in My case the records were added in the datasource. However ONLY the 1st Table is being refreshed to show the newly added record as am calling the renderrows() with the viewchild. Same is not being refreshed for the other 2 tables as the other 2 table Instances were not being picked.

Comment: Main issue is in the addElement() the like   this.table.renderRows(); Always refers to the First Table ONLY . It is not creating any instance for the other tables, eventhough a new record is being added. As a result Table is not being refreshed and the newly added record is not being shown.

Comment: Hi team, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Yaacov,  Issue is in the code this.matTable is always getting the Instance of the 1st Table only, even though we have 3 tables in the UI. So in that for the Add method every time only the datasource of the 1st table is being refreshed. Not the 2nd one or third one.

Comment: @SantoshShivaKumar did you create an ViewChild for each one of the tables using the right ID?
you need to create a ViewChild instance to each one of your tables and set there datasource as you wish

Comment: How to do that.. Because.. If you see in my ode there will be only one Table which is present in the for loop.

Comment: HI Team,Any help on this will be helpful. Am trying this for last 4 days but not able to resolve.

Comment: Any one got any idea on this one.. or do I need to write the duplicate code which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Chishty's answer, in case of 'n' tables, you can use `@ViewChildren` with a loop to call `renderRows()` on each table. Overall steps would be as follows -

1. Import `mat-table`

   import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
2. Declare `@ViewChildren` with `QueryList`

   @ViewChildren(MatTable) csvTable !: QueryList<MatTable>;
3. Call `renderRows` on add or delete operation

   this.csvTable.toArray().forEach(data => data.renderRows());
4. Remember to use the same variable as table-id in template

   <mat-table #csvTable [dataSource]="csvForm.value">

More on `@ViewChildren` - [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

More on `QueryList` - [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#properties)

Answer (score 0):

in html:

```
<table
mat-table
id="table"
class="full-width"
[dataSource]="dataSource"
matSort
data-cy="pg_table"
(matSortChange)="onSortData($event)"
#table1
>
```

in template:

```
@ViewChild('table1', { static: true }) table1: MatTable<any>;
```